# How to I disable login prompt when connecting to the Dev Board via serial console?

Tags: google-coral, mdt

I can't use mdt as I have already disabled ssh on the dev board. When connecting to the board via serial, I often get stopped with a login prompt, this makes it hard to write automated tasks. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Good question!
Please open this file:

```
/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service
```

And change the ExecStart=... line to this:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin mendel --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 %I $TERM
```

Then reboot and serial console won't be showing a login prompt any more.